# How to send an email using a html template that contains javascript django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-email

I have an email template that is rendering certain datetime strings from django. I would like to render this time based on the user's timezone. To solve this I have opted to use `momentjs` however once, it seems the javascript in the template is not run and anything wrapped in javascript doesn't appear in the email. Based from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42056995/8513875 email clients don't include external css, I assume it's the same issue with javascript, how would I go about making this recognized.

Comment: Email clients will not load or run any JS. Your application would need to know the user's timezone before the email is sent and render the email using that timezone

Comment: Is it possible to use something like https://github.com/roverdotcom/django-inlinecss as specified in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42056995/8513875  or is this just available for css.

Comment: Those packages convert CSS into inline `style` attributes on the generated HTML email. Decent email clients will __never__ support running JS attached to an email

Comment: Ohh... right thank you @IainShelvington

Comment: To specify why: JS can contain malicious code i.e. security risk

Comment: @IainShelvington any suggestions on how I can determine a user's timezone for instance based on their email?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what @IainShelvington stated, and answer...

> @oma0256
> ... how I can determine a user's timezone...

... here's how to obtain the timezone offset via JavaScript (in browser) prior to generating the email...

```
const timezone = (new Date).getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

... note again, this will **not** run within an email, but instead should be used when generating the email from whatever template the service is using.

And regarding the second part of the question...

> @oma0256
> ... for instance based on their email?

... if you're fortunate that information will be within the email headers, however, such things (much like any other client-side supplied data) cannot be trusted.

### Attribution

[MDN -- `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)